# Android ScrollView jumps up after changing child element visibility

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a ScrollView that contains elements with visibility set to View.GONE by default. The problem is that whenever this visibility changes from View.GONE to View.VISIBLE, scroll jumps up as it is shown on second picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2aKS.png

The red box represents current scroll position, blue rectangle is an element which visibility is changed, and green rectangle is some element (for example button) that I can refer to. I want my ScrollView to work as it is shown on third picture. If green button is on the screen, it should also be visible on screen after displaying new element (the blue one) above it. Any ideas how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, it behaves exacly as it should - scroll position is on e.g. 200px from top and this doesn't change when new item changes its visibility

you should scroll by yourself to proper (new) point, use [scrollTo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView#scrollTo(int,%20int)) method - measure height of this new `View` and call `scrollView.scrollTo(0, currentScrollY + heightOfNewView)`

be aware that when you change visibility then you can't call above `scrollTo` just one line below, you have to wait for this `View` being measured and drawn. so you should call `scrollTo` in e.g.

```
visibilityChangedView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
visibilityChangedView.post(new Runnable() {

        // this will be called when visibilityChangedView won't have
        // any pending tasks to do, but we just changed visibility,
        // so at first view will be measured and drawn, after that
        // below run() method will be called

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int heightOfNewView = visibilityChangedView.getMeasuredHeight();
            int currentScrollY = scrollView.getScrollY();
            scrollView.scrollTo(0, currentScrollY + heightOfNewView);
        }
);
```

there is a chance that this automatic scroll will be visible to user as quick jump - at first whole view will be drawn as #2 and after split second/one frame it will redraw at new position like #3. I don't know how your content is built (rest of childs in `Scrollview`), but I suspect that this should be `RecyclerView` or at least `ListView` with proper `Adapter`, not `ScrollView` with fixed layout

Comment: Is there any solution to avoid this quick jump?

Comment: I'm affraid no, not with usual `ScrollView`, which is desired to contain some simple static scrollable layout. In fact it is possible, but this needs a lot of code, which is already written - `ListView` and `RecyclerView` (preferred) with proper `Adapter`s may fit your needs and also this approach will be more memory-efficient

Comment: To avoid quick jump we can use `smoothScrollTo` method.

Answer (score -1):

You can use NestedScrollView. It did the job.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

Put your `scrollView` inside constraint layout and set all constraints to parent.

Comment: Add it as a comment